# Problemas al buscar una palabra en una lista

Tags: java, búsquedas

¿Cual es el problema con este codigo?

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class busqueda extends JFrame {

private List<String> nombres=new ArrayList<String>();
private JTextField nombre,_nombre;
private JButton ingrese,buscar,mostrar;

Accion accion=new Accion();
Container ce = getContentPane();
public busqueda() {

    ce.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

    nombre=new JTextField(10);
    nombre.setEditable(true);
    ce.add(nombre);

    ingrese=new JButton("Ingresar");
    ce.add(ingrese);

    _nombre=new JTextField(10);
    _nombre.setEditable(true);
    ce.add(_nombre);

    buscar= new JButton("Buscar");
    ce.add(buscar);

    mostrar=new JButton("Mostrar");
    ce.add(mostrar);


    ingrese.addActionListener(accion);
    buscar.addActionListener(accion);
    mostrar.addActionListener(accion);

    setSize(200,200);
    setVisible(true);
}

private class Accion implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
        if(e.getSource()==ingrese) {
            nombres.add(nombre.getText());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,nombre.getText()+" Agregado a 
            la Lista");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==buscar) {
            String aux=null;
            for(String n:nombres) {
                if(n==_nombre.getText()){aux=n;}
            }   
            if(aux!=null) 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,aux);
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Encontrado");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==mostrar) {
            String salida="";
            for(String n:nombres) { 
                salida+=("\n"+n);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,salida);
        }
    }
} 


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new busqueda();
}

}
```

Sinceramente no lo entiendo, si agrego "maria" y busco "maria" no lo encuentra, si es una lista de enteros si los encuentra pero con los string algo esta mal, y solo tengo este problema cuando yo ingreso la palabra por teclado a buscar, pero trabajando internamente con el codigo (sin yo ingresarlo) me los compara bien.

nota*Cualquier aclaracion o sugerencia fuera de la pregunta es bien recibida ya que apenas tengo una semana trabajando con java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las cadenas de texto en java no se comparan con `==` ya que String más que un tipo nativo es un objeto.

Para comparar un objeto en java se usa `objecto.equals(objecto_a_comparar)`, entonces tu código quedaría

```
for(String n:nombres) {
  if(n.equals(_nombre.getText())){aux=n;}
}
```

Comment: Gracias era lo que necesitaba.. pero yo estaba trabajando con el == y me funcionaba bien, el problema me lo dio cuando queria buscar un dato en especifico yo ingresandolo por teclado. por ejemplo `for(Asignatura asig:asignatura) {
   if(asig.getCodigo()==codigo)
    asig.setProf(prof);` aqui compara el codigo que esta entrado entrado obtenido directamente de un JTextField (sin yo escribirlo) con los codigos de las asignaturas guardadas, si lo encuentra añade el profesor a la asignatura. Y todo me estaba funcionando.